# Prevent gnome-shell's dash from listing Recent Items

Tags: gnome, 11.10, gnome-shell, zeitgeist, activities-overview

I am using gnome-shell in `Ubuntu 11.10`. I am getting annoyed when dash search lists **Recent Items**. I have tried many ways to prevent it like

- Deleting `activity.sqlite` and `activity.sqlite-journal` files under `~/.local/share/zeitgeist`
- Adding all the possible entries in `Activity Log Manager` to prevent application logging
- Specifying time range in `Activity Log Manager` to forget my activities.

But none of the methods are working. The recent items list is still populated.

Is there any way to tell dash not to list **Recent Items** while searching, other than the above methods? Or is there any way to **delete** the recent items list?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Gnome-shell uses recently-used and not Zeitgeist to display your recent items.

to disable it follow theses steps:

delete recently-used.xbel:

```
rm ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

create a new empty file:

```
touch ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

make sure the new file cannot be modified:

```
sudo chattr +i ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

now, your display of recent items is gone.

If you want to revert back, remove the i attribute of recently-used.xbel:

```
sudo chattr -i ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

all credits to : http://knezevblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-ubuntu-clear-and-disable-recent.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a problem here. File ~/.recently-used.xbel does not exist. What should I do?

Comment: Oops, location has changed. I'll edit my post.

Comment: No effects for me in 12.04

Comment: You can only use chattr with ext2/3/4 filesystems.

Answer (score 2):

There's also an extension [Remove recent items search provider](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/171/remove-recent-items/) for removing the Recent Items provider now, as well.

Answer (score 2):

Install " Activity Log Manager" using Synaptic and choose apps whose logs you wana see and whose not.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is [here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?p=1542486#post1542486):

```
$ cat ~/.gtkrc-2.0
gtk-recent-files-max-age=0

$ cat ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
[Settings]
gtk-recent-files-max-age=0
```

Answer (score -2):

use cairo dock to delete your recent history...
instal cairo dock first,,and then run it,,
right click on recent-events,,,then choose "Delete today's events" or "Delete all events"
I hope it can help

Comment: Hi John, can you explain better the steps to do each part you mention here. This way it helps more people that might not understand the system easily.