# Can't remove ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel

Tags: permissions

I saw this post: [Prevent gnome-shell's dash from listing Recent Items](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82584/prevent-gnome-shells-dash-from-listing-recent-items) and I'm not able to remove the recently.used.xbel file.

Do I need to be root to do this?

`-rw------- 1 ryan ryan 39157 2012-02-19 15:47 /home/ryan/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
--`

When I run

```
rm ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

I get

```
rm: cannot remove `/home/ryan/.local/share/recently-used.xbel': Operation not permitted
```

Running the same command with `sudo` returns the same error, and running nautilus as root also returns a similar error.

Comment: maybe that file is been used, try to remove on startup...

Comment: Did you set it immutable at some point with chattr?

Comment: what infinity said. Try ´sudo chattr -i ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel´, and then try to delete the file again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what infinity said. Try ´sudo chattr -i
>   ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel´, and then try to delete the file
>   again.

– @severin

This did the trick.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel* is in your home directory and belongs to your current user, so in short I can say: no, you don't need to be root to delete it.

But you need to be more specific about your problem.

Comment: When I run:

rm ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel'code'

I get  
rm: cannot remove `/home/ryan/.local/share/recently-used.xbel': Operation not permitted

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a

```
gksudo nautilus
```

or which filemanager you are using and simply browse to the file and delete it.

Comment: I still get 
     "Error removing file: Operation not permitted"

Answer (score 0):

Try running: `lsof |grep recently-used.xbel`

This should show if some process has a lock on that file.

You can also try: `rm -f ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`